# Comparing GCP datastore query performance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, query-optimization, datastore

Are both the queries same in GCP datastore in terms of speed ?

If we run both the GCP datastore queries will they perform same in terms of speed ? Which will be faster ?

Query 1 :

```
q := datastore.NewQuery(CUSTOMER).
        Order("-CreatedOn").
        Filter("CustomerKey=", userKey)
```

Query2 :

```
q := datastore.NewQuery(CUSTOMER).
    Filter("CustomerKey=", userKey).
    Order("-CreatedOn")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the exact same query.  The only difference is that you are building the query in a different order, but the RPC created is the exact same.